# alignment of text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, itemize

I am using itemize option to write a paragraph in latex. I see that left side the text is aligned well and look nice while on the right side it is not. Is there a way to make that look same as on the left side alignment?

Comment: Itemize option? Did you mean itemize environment? You should provide a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) of the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: sorry. Yes I meant \begin{itemize} my text \end{itemize}. sushil

Comment: it sounds like somewhere in your file either `raggedright` or `flushleft` is specified.  is this happening only in the `itemize` environment, or does it also happen elsewhere?  (a minimum example is really needed.)

Comment: I am using a .sty file which has this inlcuded:  \usepackage{paralist,ragged2e,datetime}  other than this I do not see any flushleft, or raggedright......I will try to produce a MWE

Comment: ah sorry, I found that .sty uses Reggedright indeed...now the problem solved..thanks -sushil

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like somewhere in your file either raggedright or flushleft is specified.

you should also observe whether this is happening only in the itemize environment, or also elsewhere, as this will help to locate the source of the problem.

in a comment, you reported that the package `ragged2e` is used, and that `Reggedright` appears in a `.sty` file, so you have now solved the problem.